# Why perfect square has odd number of factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

can someone please describe me why only the perfect square has odd number of factors.why does other number not has odd numbers of factors? I understand it but don't find any mathmetical proof.Please help me

Answer (score 13):

For a given number $n$ we can group its divisors in pairs $(d,\frac nd)$, except that if $n=m^2$ this would pair $m$ with itself.

Comment: please explain briefly

Comment: @FRM, I strongly recommend you write out examples. For this sort of mathematics, thinking about examples and non-examples is highly illuminating and will generally lead you to understand the proof.

Answer (score 6):

You can always list the factors of a number, N, into pairs $(a_i,b_i)$ where $a_i \le \sqrt N \le b_i$. This means that a number will always have an even number of factors, unless the number is a perfect square, in which case one pair will consists of the same two numbers. The two examples below should demonstrate why.

\begin{align}
    \text{factors} &\;  \text{of $36 = 6^2$} \\
    \hline
    1 &,\, 36 \\
    2 &,\, 18 \\
    3 &,\, 12 \\
    4 &,\, 9 \\
    6 &,\, 6 & \text{A total of $9$ factors} \\
    \hline
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \text{factors} &\;  \text{of $12$ } \\
    \hline
    1 &, 12 \\
    2 &, 6 \\
    3 &, 4 & \text{A total of $6$ factors} \\
    \hline
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it is counter-intuitive. The catch is that when "Factors" is written, generally what is actually meant is "unique factors". Therefor if a number is a perfect square, it will have an even number of total factors, but odd number of UNIQUE factors, which is what is truly meant.

E.g. 36: 1x36, 2x18, 3x12, 4x9, 6x6 - 10 total numbers but only 9 unique ones. For fun we just decide to ignore the second '6'.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well, without the square **root**, the square **no.** would be even. Since the square **root** is multiplied by *itself*, then there is only 1 more factor, not 2.

*Example*: 64. Has 6 factors (excluding 8 (squared)). With 8, there is now 7 factors... but not eight because the **root** (in this case, 8) will be repeated, and there is simply no point in repeating it.

I hope your question is answered! :)