# Prove that for $n\in\Bbb{Z}^+$, $n$ has an odd number of positive divisors if and only if $n$ is the square of an integer.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Actually I am a new student of discrete mathematics and this question is weird for me. Can anyone help me?

I think that here we will use the theorem that every integer is written in the form of product of primes and then we argue by saying that it is a square because for divisors to be odd the power of primes must be even or something like that.
Can you guys please help me out!
*Using number theory*

Comment: Suppose $n$ has positive divisors $2,3,5$. Then is $n$ a square of an integer?

Comment: What is this? I didn't get this. Bcz I am looking for proof. I know this is true but how can I prove this?

Comment: You're on the right track. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: @Manjoy Das Those are prime divisors that multiply to 30. 30 has divisors 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30 which is an even number of divisors.

Comment: Guys, sorry but do you have clear Explaination or something like proof for this?

Comment: My suggestion is that you calculate the number of divisors of each number from 1 to 20. Write a list, the number, the full prime factorization as primes with exponents (if larger than 1), and the count of divisors. Everything you are writing says that you have never done such calculations. You can keep demanding that we give you a proof, or you can learn most of it yourself in a fairly short time

Comment: Read the Wikipedia page on the divisor function, specifically regarding the properties section. Note $\sigma_0(p^n) = n+1$ and that if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $\sigma_x(a*b) = \sigma_x(a) \sigma_x(b)$. The purpose of this site is to guide you to an answer, not to give one out, so that you understand the process

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why perfect square has odd number of factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525935/why-perfect-square-has-odd-number-of-factors)

Comment: You don’t need prime factorization. Just pair each divisor $d$ of $n$ with the divisor $\frac{n}d$.

Comment: @Ryanshesler the op nowhere mentioned the divisors could be composite. So according to the title that the op chose, i can take only prime divisors. It could be added that $n$ has an odd number of complete list of positive divisors.

Comment: @ManjoyDas the default definition of divisor of $m$, unless otherwise specified, is an integer $n$ such that $m$ is a multiple of $n$ or $n \vert m$, not that $m$ is a multiple of $n$ with $n$ prime.

Comment: @Ryanshesler yes you're right. But what i think is an addition of 'complete list' would have been more appropiate to avoid misunderstanding like i made.